# Pipeline fails when using try/catch in parallel

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm quite new to the pipelines and have been reading some official tutorials. I have been trying to figure out how to use `try/catch` in a node which is running in `parallel`. I'm following the [official example](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#executing-in-parallel). Here is some code:

```
stage('Test') {
    parallel linux: {
        node('linux') {
            checkout scm
            try {
                unstash 'app'
                sh 'make check'
            }
            finally {
                junit '**/target/*.xml'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running pretty much the same code with only node labels changed. However I received the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 23: Expected a step @ line 23, column 29.
                           try {
                           ^
```

Anybody has an idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace 'script' to 'steps', its work well in my side

```
stage('Test') {
parallel linux: {
    node('linux') {
        script {
            checkout scm
            try {
                unstash 'app'
                sh 'make check'
            }
            finally {
                junit '**/target/*.xml'
            }
      }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way to do it. I found that a couple of months ago but forgot to post it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that you are running the version of Pipeline plugin, where this syntax is deprecated (yes, it happens even if you take an example from official documentation...)
I would advice you to do like:

```
 stage('Test') {
    steps {
        parallel (
           node('linux') {
            "firstTask" : {
                // Do your try/catch etc.
            }
           },
           node('linux') { //or some other slave name
            "secondTask" : {
                // Do some other thing in parallel
            }
           }
        )
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work, try to play with the steps, since the cause of mistake is linked to them:

```
stage('Test') {
    parallel linux: {
        node('linux') {
            steps {
            checkout scm
            try {
                unstash 'app'
                sh 'make check'
            }
            finally {
                junit '**/target/*.xml'
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

or:

```
stage('Test') {
    parallel linux: {
        node('linux') {
            checkout scm
            try {
               steps {
                unstash 'app'
                sh 'make check'
               }
            }
            finally {
                junit '**/target/*.xml'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working as well. I receive the same error.